# Amazon Certificate Manager SSL "Waiting for verification"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I'm going to issue a domain using AWS and get a certificate for it.

I'm Already done about "Creating a Record on Route 53"

So CNAME connect Domain record at route53

But there was no change in the three days.

I don't know why.

record name

> _46d694d9098a0509da42f7474b05799e.loocusvision.link

value

> _5961b971439a970ca78f21d67e976d24.btkxpdzscj.acm-validations.aws.

record name

> _f7ba2e06931d426acbc3cb7a0e5592ac.www.loocusvision.link

value

> _67bfb83981ee35cb105aa4de419d3d70.btkxpdzscj.acm-validations.aws.

Comment: Double check the type of record and the values are exactly what was asked.  Sometimes if you copy/paste you might miss a simple value.

Comment: The problem typically means you did not create the DNS resource records exactly as requested. Without more details, we can only guess.